# How can i run SIP demo successfully

Tags: android

I have tried to run sip demo but it always give me voip, sip and manager as null value. I have run on android 4.0.3(API level 15), android 2.3.3(API level 10) and android 3.1(API level 12) in the emulator. I have also tried to run on Samsung Galaxy Y(2.3.6), but the manager come as null. Now anyone can give me solution for successfully running this SIP demo? On which device it will run? Is it possible to run on emulator?

I have given all the permissions correctly. I am using asterisk for getting the call. If I try from softphone, then Asterisk gets the call but from the SIP demo, there is no action in asterisk.

Please give any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.Download the `system.img` file from the link http://xilard.hyl.
put that file in `/root/.android/avd/<your avd folder>`.Then run SIP demo it will return sip and voip as `true` and manager will not come as `null`.